# Trying to get the newest innerHTML text of a label

Tags: javascript

I have a function that queries a database for info, when a button is clicked. This info gets written to innerHTML of a label. When this function returns, I read the innerHTML of this label. Problem is, it always returns the old value, not the new value that was pulled from the database. The label on the scree is displaying the correct value, though. When I click the button again, the value that I was expecting on the previous click, is now given. Seems like a timing issue but can't seem to figure it out.
example:
SQL Data - cost = 10

I expect to see 10 alerted to me when I click the button. I get a blank alerted to me, even though 10 is now in the label. When I click the button again, 10 is alerted, but 20 is now in the label.

```
function getInfo() {
    var ctlMonthly = document.getElementById("cellMonthlyCost")
    getSQLData(ctlMonthly);
    alert(ctlMonthly.innerHTML);
} 

function getSQLData(ctlCell){
    ...
    var my_ctlCell = document.getElementById(ctlCell);
    $.each(objData.items, function() {
      my_ctlCell.innerHTML = this.Param1
    });
    ...
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You send an element as `ctlMonthly` in `getSQLData(ctlMonthly);` then inside the function you get `document.getElementById(ctlCell);` being `ctlCell` the `ctlMonthly`. Is that right?

Comment: why are you mixing JQuery with native JavaScript???... you can do it with JQuery... $('#cellMonthlyCost').html("what ever you want")... and read it $('#cellMonthlyCost').html()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to piggyback on Himanshu's answer, your request to your server is async. Meaning javascript will execute the GET request and continue on with the script, when the requests comes back from the server it will run whatever callback you give it. ( i.e. update label tag )

assuming `getSQLData` is a ajax call or something promised based, something like:

```
function getSQLData(ctlCell){
  return $.get('/sql/data').done(function () {
    var my_ctlCell = document.getElementById(ctlCell);
    $.each(objData.items, function() {
      my_ctlCell.innerHTML = this.Param1
    });
  });
}
```

you can change your code to:

```
function getInfo() {
  var ctlMonthly = document.getElementById("cellMonthlyCost")
  getSQLData(ctlMonthly)
    .done(function () {
      alert(ctlMonthly.innerHTML);
    });
}
```

Basically the difference is your telling javascript to alert the innerHTML **after** the requests comes back from the server.

**The more correct answer** would be to alert the data straight from the response instead of reading from the DOM.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, getSQLData makes an ajax call to a web service. I am reading from the DOM because this data is getting inserted into a new row of a table. This table is dynamic so it can have any number of rows. I am trying to calculate a total cost for everything in the table. So with this, I can just loop through all the labels in the table and sum the values. Thanks for all the responses, they were very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the alert after the data is received from the database.  I am assuming that you're sending an ajax request to fetch data. You will be able to get the new value in the callback of you're ajax request function.
Currently what is happening in your code is that

```
1.  getSQLData(ctlMonthly);
// This sends a request to the data base to fetch data
2. alert(ctlMonthly.innerHTML);
// This shows the current value in an alert
3. data is received and shown in the label
```

This process happens so fast that you don't notice the difference between step 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?
I used a callback function

```
    function getInfo() {
         var ctlMonthly = document.getElementById("cellMonthlyCost")
         getSQLData(ctlMonthly,alertInfo);

    } 
    function alertInfo(info){
        alert(info);
    }
    function getSQLDate(ctlCell,callbackFn){
        ...
        var my_ctlCell = document.getElementById(ctlCell);
        $.each(objData.items, function() {
          my_ctlCell.innerHTML = this.Param1;
          callbackFn(this.Param1);
        });
        ...
    }
```